# QuickSort Algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to write a recursive program for a QuickSort algorithm. Here's my code so far:

```
void QuickSort(int *array, int first, int last){
  int q;
  if (first<last){
    q = partition(array,first,last);
    QuickSort(array,first,q-1);
    QuickSort(array,q+1,last);
  }
}

void partition(int *A, int p, int r){
  int value = A[r];
  i = p-1;
  int tmp;
  for (j = p; j<=r; j++){
    if (A[j] <= value) {
      i++;
      tmp = A[i];
      A[i] = A[j];
      A[j] = tmp;
    }
  }
return(i);
}

int main(){                                                                            
  int numArray[8] = {30,15,11,40,75,80,70,60};
  int i;

  printf("Before sorting: \n");
  for (i = 0; i<8; i++) printf("numArray[%d] = %d\n", i, numArray[i]);

  int first = 0;
  int last = sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(numArray[0]);
  QuickSort(numArray,first,last-1);

  printf("After sorting: \n");
  for (i = 0; i<8; i++) printf("numArray[%d] = %d\n", i, numArray[i]);
}
```

My problem is that when I run this, I get stuck in an infinite loop when I get to the first recursion call (just after partition). Also, what I've noticed is that the recursion call is ran on the array values of A[0] - A[5], even though it should be on A[0]-A[3]. I'm not expecting a complete answer, but maybe a hint on why the program is stuck in that infinite would be extremely helpful.

Comment: The code has many errors that stop it from compiling.  Once these are fixed, the code works for me.  One interesting fix is to change `partition` to return `int` rather than `void`

Comment: My comment actually goes through the entire array from the beginning, and the pivot is actually the last number in the array. I understand what you're saying, but we're (as an algorithms class at my college) only working from the beginning, not from both ends of the array like you suggested

Comment: I meant to say 'code' instead of 'comment' above

Comment: @user3342662 - do not edit the important original content of your post.  It confuses matters when others attempt to address an issue, then all of the sudden the problem you stated has been changes, or eliminated.

Comment: @ryyker the only change I made was declaring 'int i' in the main() function because one of the users below said it was undeclared, when in my program I actually had 'i' declared as a global variable. Otherwise, the code was left untouched. So, in response to your comment, I honestly have no idea what the fuss is about.

Comment: :) - my point exactly.  (not a big fuss, just a little one.  Simply suggest not changing your OP, except perhaps for formatting and readability improvements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did with your outline and it seems to be working and sorting fine.
I replaced the void with an int, and declared int's as necessary

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int partition(int *A, int p, int r){
    int value = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    int tmp;
    for (int j = p; j<=r; j++){
        if (A[j] <= value) {
        i++;
        tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = tmp;
        }
   }
return(i);
}
void QuickSort(int *array, int first, int last){
    int q;
    if (first<last){
        q = partition(array,first,last);
        QuickSort(array,first,q-1);
        QuickSort(array,q+1,last);
    }
}



int main(){
    int numArray[8] = {30,15,11,40,75,80,70,60};

    printf("Before sorting: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) printf("numArray[%d] = %d\n", i, numArray[i]);

    int first = 0;
    int last = sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(numArray[0]);
    QuickSort(numArray,first,last-1);

    printf("After sorting: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) printf("numArray[%d] = %d\n", i, numArray[i]);
}
```